# (Processing / MySQL / Java) Unable to query database value?

Tags: java, mysql, processing

I am creating a track selector program which works in conjunction with a MySQL database.

The song information is in the database as 'Title, Artist, Album, Year, BPM'.

You load the song into the program and the program will play the song. However, after the song is finished, it needs to find another song to play directly after - a song with a similar BPM.

The program will query the database and find a suitable match for the current song in terms of a BPM in a similar range (currently I have set the range to +1)

The error I am getting is: **SQL.next(): You need to query() something first?**

How am I able to rectify this please?

```
if (dbconnection.connect()) {
    //get the same title
    dbconnection.query("SELECT * FROM music WHERE Title ='" + title + "'");
    while (dbconnection.next()) {
      if (meta.title().equals(dbconnection.getString("Title"))) {
        println(dbconnection.getString("BPM"));
      }
      dbconnection.query("SELECT * FROM music WHERE BPM >" + dbconnection.getString("BPM") + 
      "order by BPM asc limit 1");
      println(dbconnection.getString("Title"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should go over some [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) first.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?